# how to write on the columns row header in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

how to write on the columns row header in datagridview 
I mean the header of the columns row headers 
Like this

[image]

and this is my code

```
dataGridView1.Rows[-1].HeaderCell.Value = "Days";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Days";
```

Comment: No, he wants `dataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Days";`

Comment: @TaW, ok you are more correct.